Calculate days forward coverage
I have a dataframe df
Week     Product    Location    Demand  Target  
01/04/2024  A123    L999    109.011091  1680  
08/04/2024  A123    L999    107.085798  1680  
15/04/2024  A123    L999    108.982414  1680  
22/04/2024  A123    L999    107.059032  1680  
29/04/2024  A123    L999    108.956534  1680  
06/05/2024  A123    L999    107.034876  1680  
13/05/2024  A123    L999    108.933176  1680  
20/05/2024  A123    L999    107.013076  1680  
27/05/2024  A123    L999    108.912096  1680  
03/06/2024  A123    L999    106.993401  1680  
10/06/2024  A123    L999    108.893071  1680  
17/06/2024  A123    L999    106.975644  
24/06/2024  A123    L999    108.875901  
01/07/2024  A123    L999    566.636709  
08/07/2024  A123    L999    611.998169  
15/07/2024  A123    L999    582.081501  
22/07/2024  A123    L999    612.327427  

I need to calculate days forward coverage of the target for each week.
I've tried excel formula is
=ROUNDUP((SUMPRODUCT(--(C5>=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C4:$U4,,,,COLUMN(C4:$U4)-COLUMN(C4)+1))))+ABS(LOOKUP(0,(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C4:$U4,,,,COLUMN(C4:$U4)-COLUMN(C4)+1))-C5-C4:$U4)/C4:$U4)))*7,6)

and this produces the output I am looking for, however I have 5,000+ products, 8 locations and 13 weeks to iterate over.
This is what I am expecting
Week     Product    Location    Demand  Target  Days Cover  
01/04/2024  A123    L999    109.011091  1680    94.400622  
08/04/2024  A123    L999    107.085798  1680    88.747301  
15/04/2024  A123    L999    108.982414  1680    83.070196  
22/04/2024  A123    L999    107.059032  1680    77.385648  
29/04/2024  A123    L999    108.956534  1680    71.610183  
06/05/2024  A123    L999    107.034876  1680    65.856421  
13/05/2024  A123    L999    108.933176  1680    60.08068  
20/05/2024  A123    L999    107.013076  1680    54.326652  
27/05/2024  A123    L999    108.912096  1680    48.550661  
03/06/2024  A123    L999    106.993401  1680    42.837323  
10/06/2024  A123    L999    108.893071  1680    37.124005  
17/06/2024  A123    L999    106.975644      
24/06/2024  A123    L999    108.875901      
01/07/2024  A123    L999    566.636709      
08/07/2024  A123    L999    611.998169      
15/07/2024  A123    L999    582.081501      
22/07/2024  A123    L999    612.327427      


Could you perhaps explain your excel formula in terms of the columns of your dataframe? That might make it easier to get a working answer

Here's a solution using np.interp to perform linear interpolation of the target + cumulative_demand into cumulative_demand returning the cumulative days.
import numpy as np
    
demand = np.array( [109.011091, 107.085798, 108.982414, 107.059032, 108.956534,
                    107.034876, 108.933176, 107.013076, 108.912096, 106.993401,
                    108.893071, 106.975644, 108.875901, 566.636709, 611.998169,
                    582.081501, 612.327427] )
tgt = np.array( 11*[ 1680 ])
cum_days = np.arange( 0, len(demand)*7, 7 )  # Can be changed if not always by week.

cum_demand = demand.cumsum()
lead_cum_demand = cum_demand - demand

tgt_plus_demand = tgt + lead_cum_demand[:11]

cover_days = np.interp( tgt_plus_demand, lead_cum_demand, cum_days ) - cum_days[:11]
# Linear interpolation of cum_days from tgt_plus_demand into lead_cum_demand

print( cover_days )

# [94.40062195 88.74730074 83.07019524 77.38564721 71.61018229 65.85642088
#  60.08067966 54.32665109 48.55066052 42.83732215 37.12400418]

I don't understand enough pandas to know how to organise the product data from pandas into suitable numpy arrays.
